2022 Q3 Activity Support Proposals
I'm opening another opportunity to request support for asking and answering questions on our site. We've done this before, and we've had some great results.
I will be accepting proposals here until Friday, September 23rd. I'm very open to input from anyone on this process. However, because I have to report back to TLG how these sets were used, final decisions over what is approved will be at my discretion. Important factors for me will be community feedback for a user's proposal (via comments and votes here), as well as the quality of content that a user generally creates.
I have some ideas I've been mulling over, but I'm very happy to spread this support around to support the community as much as possible.
Users submitting proposals must meet the following requirements:

You must have earned at least 200 rep in 2022 or 1k rep total.
You may not resell these sets. This is a TLG requirement.
The requested set(s) need to be prominently featured in at least one question. Your question(s) should be part of the proposal to receive your set(s). The question will likely be self-answered by you and should be tagged as activity-support. Alternatively, I'm open to other non-Q&A creative uses of these sets as well (social media campaigns, etc) as long as they serve the core purpose of our community.
You must be committed to completing your proposed work before the end of the year.

For this support request, we are restricted to the following:

667 EUR
10 items total, up to 5 copies of the same set
Maximum of 5 addresses on the request

Update: It looks like we don't have any proposals this round, so I'm going to move forward with some of my own ideas. Feel free to share any ideas you have regarding use of activity support in the future.
